# setLayerDefinitions without defining layers?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am working on a similar project to [How to zoom to feature when clicking on drop-down list box item with ArcGIS JS API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41496/how-to-zoom-to-feature-when-clicking-on-drop-down-list-box-item-with-arcgis-js-a/48572#comment63534_48572), trying to filter the graphics on my map based on the user input into a FilteringSelect. The overall methodology of how my app is set up is that I go from a queryTask into a forEach loop that calls map.graphics.add(graphic) for each encountered feature returned from the queryTask.

I was hoping to be able to use the map.getLayer("dynamic").setLayerDefinitions(...) function to filter the map results based on user input, but from what I can tell that's not possible here since I don't define layers. Is there any way to accomplish this filtering with the setup I am currently using?

Comment: Since I am displaying graphics on top of a basemap, does the concept of layers even apply here?