# How to set the map extent so as to show conccurently all the features included in different map layers

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, extents, zoom

I want to load may diffent layers on my map using the ArcGis JS API.
I want to set my map's extent so as to show all the features of all the layers concurrently.
In other words I am looking for the extent that contains all my layers graphics and zoom to it.

How can I tell the map to find and zoom to a specific extent that will include all that features?
Is there any way other than iterating over all the features, like it is happening in the suggested solution of the [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28394/automatic-zoom-to-layer-in-arcgis-js-api) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through all graphicsLayer's graphics and store them in an array.
Use the graphicsUtils graphicsExtent method to get the extent of the array.

```
require([
  "esri/graphicsUtils" , "dojo/_base/array"
], function(graphicsUtils, arrayUtils) {

var allGraphics = [];
arrayUtils.forEach(map.graphicsLayerIds, function(graphicLayerId){
    allGraphics = allGraphics.concat(map.getLayer(graphicLayerId).graphics);
});
  var myFeatureExtent = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(allGraphics);
});
```

The graphicsExtent method is documented here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.graphicsutils-amd.html#graphicsextent